# What are the properties of the back arc extension related volcanic rocks?

Tags: magmatism

What are the properties of the back arc extension related volcanic rocks and/or related magma? (e.g. Basin and Range region)

Comment: Muharrem, many of your questions can be potentially answered from these two papers: https://authors.library.caltech.edu/94439/1/32-1_arculus.pdf and https://doi.org/10.1130/GES01661.1

Answer (score 1):

Back arc basin lavas are basaltic and similar to the magma from mid ocean ridges, except that the magma from back arc basins is about four times as rich in magmatic water, which is typically 1.5 percent by weight of the rock.

Comment: At back arc basins there are subalkali basalts chemically different to mid-ridge MORB basalts.